# How to supress Connext warning in ROS2

Tags: ros, suppress-warnings, ros2

Is there a way to suppress this annoying warning that appears each time I run the bash after sourcing `ros2` in `~/.bashrc` without using `Connext`?

```
[connext_cmake_module] Warning: 
The location at which Connext was found when the workspace was built 
[[/opt/rti.com/rti_connext_dds-5.3.1]] 
does not point to a valid directory, and the NDDSHOME environment variable has not been set. 
Support for Connext will not be available.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All this warning is saying is that `Connext` has been built with support for for another RMW implementation that isn't the default. If you're not actively trying to use `connext_dds` you can safely ignore the error. If you want to actually use this, or a non-default, RMW it is done by setting the environmental variable `$RMW_IMPLEMENTATION` and can be changed by doing one of the following:

```
export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_fastrtps_cpp
export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_opensplice_cpp
export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_connext_cpp
```

The default for the newest distro(foxy) is `Fast-RTPS`.

Comment: "*you can safely ignore the error*" it is a warning actually, and I'm looking to suppress it not to ignore it, I have already read this point on [ROS-answers](https://answers.ros.org/question/323501/problem-with-ros2-installation/?answer=323538#post-id-323538), but I'm looking for a  solution to **suppress the warning** because it bothers me.

Comment: @Bilal I'm repeating that point because it's what you **should** do. Warnings exist for a reason and here suppressing and ignoring are the same thing. If you truly want to suppress the warning you would need to build the package from source editing the `CMakeLists.txt` option `target_compile_options()` or just redirect the command output in your `.bashrc` to `/dev/null`. Both of these options are extremely poor ideas and design. It absolutely can, and probably will, break other systems down the line.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use Connext DDS anymore you can just run

```
sudo apt purge ros-foxy-rmw-connext-cpp
sudo apt purge ros-foxy-connext-cmake-module
```